# Не правильно работает скрипт js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Задача стоит такая - показывать и скрывать блок по нажатию на кнопку, решил это сделать через js/jquery с помощью fadeIn и fadeOut...оно работает, т.к. по умолчанию блок не отображается(display:none), а при нажатии на кнопку  появляться. Суть проблемы в том, что при повторном нажатии скрипт уже перестает срабатывать правильно( блок появляться на пару секунд и закрывается). В чем может быть проблема?

сам код:

```
$('.btn-down-1').click(function(){
    $("#myShowBlock").fadeIn("slow");
    //$(".btn-up").css("visibility","visible");
    $(".btn-down-1").removeClass().text("Закрыть").addClass('btn-up');

    $('.btn-up').click(function(){

        $("#myShowBlock").fadeOut();
        $(".btn-up").removeClass().text("Показать больше").addClass('btn-down-1');

    });
```

});

Comment: "Не правильно работает скрипт js/jQuery" - может Вы неправильно им пользуетесь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы встали на скользкий путь навешивания обработчиков событий в других обработчиках событий.

> "Вы погубите себя, сын мой." Александр Дюма

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-down-1", function(){
  $("#myShowBlock").fadeIn("slow");
  $(this).removeClass("btn-down-1").text("Закрыть").addClass("btn-up");
});

$(document).on("click", ".btn-up", function(){
  $("#myShowBlock").fadeOut();
  $(this).removeClass("btn-up").text("Показать больше").addClass("btn-down-1");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек))

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-up, .btn-down-1', function() {
  const $button = $(this),
    buttonDown = $button.hasClass('btn-down-1');
    
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-up btn-down-1').text(buttonDown ? 'Закрыть' : 'Показать больше');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-down-1">Показать больше</button>
```